# Printing a class attribute instead of its memory address?

Tags: python, class, oop

For the sake of knowledge, I would like to print the contents of the class attribute list `all_contacts` of this code:

```py
class Contact:
    all_contacts = []

    def __init__(self,name,email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        Contact.all_contacts.append(self)
```

However, all my attempts result in a memory address:

```
>>> c = Contact("Some Body", "somebody@example.net")
>>> c2 = Contact("Some Body 2", "somebody2@example.net")

>>> Contact.all_contacts
[<__main__.Contact object at 0x0000000002C8CF48>]

>>> print(Contact.all_contacts)
[<__main__.Contact object at 0x0000000002C8CF48>]

>>> c.all_contacts
[<__main__.Contact object at 0x0000000002C8CF48>]
```

How do I print this class attribute so I can see it's elements?

Comment: You are printing it. You added `self` to `all_contacts`, and `Contact`, when printed is `<__main__.Contact object at 0x0000000002C8CF48>` because you didn't define a `__str__` or `__repr__` for `Contact`. Note the `[]` around the output indicating that it's printing a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to implement `__repr__()` as required:

```
class Contact:
    all_contacts = []

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        Contact.all_contacts.append(self)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Name:{self.name} Email:{self.email}"

c = Contact("Some Body", "somebody@example.net")
c2 = Contact("Some Body 2", "somebody2@example.net")

print( Contact.all_contacts)
```

Output:

```
[Name:Some Body Email:somebody@example.net, Name:Some Body 2 Email:somebody2@example.net]
```

Comment: If you are using Python 3.8+, you can use the following f-string to get the same output while writing less code: `<Contact {self.name=} {self.email=}>`